# How do I mock a class marked final and has a private constructor using jMockit

Tags: java, unit-testing, jmockit

I would like to write some state based tests using `JMockit` to mock up [CSVRecord](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVRecord.html).  The problem is that `CSVRecord` is `final` (which means I have to use a mocking framework like `JMockit`) and `CSVRecord's` constructor has package private visibility.

Since it is package private, I can't call new `CSVRecord(arg, arg, ...)`, which means I can never I instantiate my mock.
 Its parent, CSVParser, is the only class that can create an instance.

Does `JMockit` have a way to deal with this scenario?

note: `JMockit` or `Mockito` are the only frameworks we use on this project.  No other framework will be acceptable.  My  preference is to use a MockUp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds more like `CSVRecord` isn't a good candidate for mocking. If possible, tests targetting another public class which uses it internally would be preferable.

Otherwise, JMockit provides a `Deencapsulation` class with `newInstance` methods.

As a side note, Mockito only supports behavior-based tests; JMockit provides "mock-ups" (`MockUp`), but it's not the same as writing a pure state-based black box test.

Comment: Thanks. Possible to show a solution using Deencapsulation.newInstance to get a reference to a CSVRecord?

Comment: Just call it passing `CSVRecord.class` as the first argument, followed by any other arguments the desired constructor in `CSVRecord` has.

Comment: Deprecated answer as Deencapsulation doesn't have the newInstance method.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just a matter of calling the private constructor, then yes, JMockit has tools to deal with that. See the [tutorial](http://jmockit.org/tutorial/Mocking.html#deencapsulation)

Comment: Old link that doesn't work. Very unhelpful answer as it basically says to look at Jmockit's documentation which is gigantic.

Answer (score -1):

Use:

`ConstructorReflection.newInstance`

in newer versions of Jmockit.

Comment: You forgot to mention that `ConstructorReflection` is an *internal* class (and therefore not part of JMockit's published API), and as such should never be used by user code as it may be changed or even removed in future versions. BTW, the only good answer to this question is what I wrote in the first paragraph of my answer: do *not* mock `CSVRecord`, it's a terrible idea since it's just an implementation detail of `CSVParser`.

Comment: Internal classes aren't usually labeled as "public" unless the developers are a little behind on their OO skills. https://github.com/jmockit/jmockit1/blob/master/main/src/mockit/internal/reflection/ConstructorReflection.java

Comment: What? Sorry, but you have no idea what you're saying... The use of "internal" packages (containing public classes, *of course*) is a standard convention in the Java language, since it didn't have support for modules until Java 9. The Eclipse project, for example, uses this convention.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided another option or answer to this, as turning down something that works just fine isn't helpful.